# Class 'Craft\stdClass' not found

Tags: plugin-development, plugins

Is there any way to initialize a stdClass? 
Code is simple

```
    $productOrCategory  =   new stdClass();
    $productOrCategory->stockFutureDays = 0;
    $productOrCategory->stockFutureDate = date('ymd');
```

but im getting **Fatal error**:  Class 'Craft\stdClass' not found in **Controller.php** on line **63**
 and line 63 is the first line i added as code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solution was to call

```
$productOrCategory  =   new \stdClass();
```