# Using XMLReader With Plugin

Tags: plugin-development, php, xml, classes

In my project, I have a reference to XMLReader in a plugin; however, I get this error message:

```
Class 'Craft\XMLReader' not found
```

Here is the code which calls it:

```
$reader = new XMLReader();
```

Can XMLReader be used within Craft, or can there be a customization which would allow it?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to be in the correct namespace try

```
$reader = new \XMLReader();
```

Like [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/5311/class-craft-stdclass-not-found)